# SQL to see records if their value in one column has changed

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have the following four columns:

- DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST (the first time a person purchase a subscription, eg: 2008)
- Subscription_ID  (Can have multiple subscriptions in the past, so multiple subscription ids)
- START_DATE_AEST (the start date of their current subscription)
- Subscription_Status (Whether their subscription is active or they've lapsed)

I want to write a query that displays a list of records, who've previously had a subscription, and their last subscription_status was lapsed and is now active.

So I wrote something basic as:

`m.START_DATE_AEST > c.DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST` - this tells me that they've previously had a subscription
`AND m.START_DATE_AEST = convert(date, getDate())` - check if the start date is today

But I don't know how to write something that says: If someone's subscription_status was 'lapsed' yesterday and today, the subscription_status has changed to 'Active'

Answer (score 0):

If your data extension gets updated every day, you would have to keep a copy of yesterday's data in another data extension and compare the two statuses (on today's data and yesterday's data) based on `Subscription_ID`. This is assuming that the same `Subscription_ID` can be `active` after being `lapsed`. Is that the case or a new subscription record is created for the now `Active` subscription?

Comment: Thanks Lucas. It's the latter, a new subscription record is created for the Now Active subscription. 
So the same data extension has old subscription ids and new/current ones too.